# C program still misses some output after flushing IO buffer

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork, flush

The following C program misses some output even after flushing the IO buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void fork2() {
    printf("(L0 %d) ", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
    printf("(L1 %d) ", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
    printf("(Bye %d) ", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main() {
    printf("parent: %d\n", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    fork2();
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output of the above program is like the following, which has 7 tuples.

```
parent: 26874
(L0 26874) (L1 26874) (Bye 26874) (L1 26875) (Bye 26876) (Bye 26875) (Bye 26877)
```

However, I run it multiple times. Its output is not always like this. Sometimes it misses part of the output at the end like following, which contains less than 7 tuples.

```
parent: 26882
(L0 26882) (L1 26882) (Bye 26882) (L1 26883) (Bye 26884) (Bye 26883)
```

Why the program misses some output even after flushing the IO buffer?

Won't the program flush IO buffer automatically before exit?

[UPDATE]

This sreenshot shows my shell when I run multiple times continuously.

[image: screenshot]

But my another machine acts in a different way like following.

[image]

Comment: One possibility is that the second fork fails in either the parent or child — you don't test, so you wouldn't know.  Do you get anything different in the behaviour (no missed output) if you use a newline at the end of each `printf()` — does it only cause problems when you try to put all the output on a single line?  Do you get any enlightenment if you print `getppid()`as well as `getpid()` in the `printf()` statements in `fork2()`?  The second `fflush()` in `main()` should be (is) superfluous.

Comment: None of your processes waits for its children to die before exiting.  Could it be that the first program exits and the shell prompt obliterates the output from the as-yet undead children?  Does anything change if you pipe the output of your program to a program such as `cat` (or `less` or `more`)?  Your sample output doesn't show your shell prompt appearing after the data printed by the program.

Comment: I added error check after each `fork` and ran again. The `fork`s didn't fail when part of the output be missed. However, if I use a newline at the end of each `printf`, the output is always as expected. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: What about if you pipe the output to a program (`cat` for example)?  Or redirect to a file?  Does using `>>` (append) make any difference?  In case you've not gathered, it isn't obvious why it is not working as expected, so I'm clutching at straws.

Comment: If I run this program using `./a.out | cat`, its output is as expeacted. Using `>>` is also works as expected. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I'm beginning to think your 'terminal' program is misbehaving.  That's unusual, but not actually impossible (it is software; it has bugs).  But it is surprising that it is causing this sort of trouble (or, at least, I'm surprised by it).  I don't have a good explanation for how things can be going wrong otherwise.  Maybe someone else will have some inspiration.

Comment: Hmmm; the second example shows one of the processes writing after the first completes and the shell has reprinted its prompt.  I suspect that this may be happening on the other machine (the first machine) too.  Can you try setting your prompt to just `"$ "` or something equally simple (`PS1='$ '`).  Then try your test.  I suspect that your prompt is complex enough that it trashes what else was written.  Still somewhat guesswork.  I'm pretty sure that adding a `wait()` loop at the end of the program would force the expected behaviour, too.

Comment: As you said earlier, the first program exits and the shell prompt obliterates the output from the as-yet undead children. I think it is probable to be the reason. So pipe output and redirect can get expected output. Why don't you think so now? However, I can't figure out why adding a newline at the end of each `printf` can get expected output. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I executed `export PS1='$ '` on my machine used in my first example and ran my test again. It works the same as before. I think it is due to other shell configuration. I'm also pretty sure that adding a `wait()` loop at the end of the program would force the expected behaviour. So I hold the opinion what my last comment said. @JonathanLeffler